# Code runs from interpreter but not in editor

Tags: python, unicode

I am trying to add some symbols to a text file, I can not define these symbols in the editor but it works from the command line.

`symbols = '$¢£¥€¤'` works in the interpreter but not the editor (Sublime Text), however, it doesn't print these symbols correctly in command. If I do `decode("utf-8")`, then print works fine.

```
symbols = '$¢£¥€¤'
s=symbols.decode("utf-8")
```

I use Python 2.7 and Sublime Text

this is the error I get when I run using the editor

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc2' in file /home/programmer/Desktop/seleniumIns.py on line 184, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

How can I fix these to add them to my original program in the editor?

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesn't print these symbols correctly in command"?

Comment: Also do you have something like `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of your file, and does Sublime save it as UTF8?

Comment: @RemcoGerlich i get � instead of actual character (except for $ that prints fine)

Comment: @AmjasdMasdhash, if you are a Python beginner, you should definitely switch to Python 3. There, you can omit the `# coding: utf-8` declaration (because UTF-8 is the default source-code encoding) and also the `.decode('utf8')` part (because strings are Unicode strings).

Comment: @lenz i have been using python for over a year now,python 2 can differ between `unicode` and `str` unlike python 3 Also  `print "Hello world"` instead `print ("Hello world")`  :-D

Comment: Exactly – you already know two key differences, so why still bother with Python 2 – it's a pain for dealing with Unicode text. Also, it's being discontinued next year.

Comment: @lenz January 1, 2020 is my **Friday the 13th**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run a python file containing unicode, you need to tell the interpreter what encoding is used.
In your case put at the very first line of your script this line:

`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

And you'll be able to use utf-8!

Comment: This works,i will have to use  `decode("utf-8")` whenever i use them

Comment: `decode("utf-8")` will give you a 8-bit string version of the Unicode string. Have a look at [this paragraph](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type).

Comment: @edwinburton it's the other way round: `'...'.decode('utf8')` turns an 8-bit string into a Unicode string.