# Python match-case return statement works in an interpreter but doesn't work in a text editor

Tags: python

I am looking at the [official python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.10/tutorial/controlflow.html) for educational purposes and I tried this simple match case codes below:

```
def http_error(status):
    match status:
        case 400:
            return "Bad request"
        case 404:
            return "Not found"
        case 418:
            return "I'm a teapot"
        case _:
            return "Something's wrong with the internet"
```

I noticed that the `return` keyword works only in an interpreter but didn't seem to work in my text editor until I changed it to a `print` statement. For the purpose of understanding, can anyone clarify why this happened? I've looked at similar  questions such as [Return statement not working in sublime text editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61844226/return-statement-not-working-in-sublime-text-editor) and [code runs from interpreter but not in editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54469142/code-runs-from-interpreter-but-not-in-editor) but it's either I'm missing something or it's not related to this match-case scenario.

Thanks.

Comment: What does "didn't seem to work in my text editor" mean?

Comment: It wasn't running at all on my text editors. I had thought it was a bug in the code. I used VS code, IDLE and Sublime Text but to no avail. The moment I tried the same code on the interpreter, it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return` "returns" value, and that's it.  Python interpreter prints return value, therefore there's no noticeable difference between `>>> 2 + 3` and `>>> print(2 + 3)`.  If you want to see result printed, print it.  "match-case" is irrelevant here, and answers to [Return statement not working in sublime text editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61844226/return-statement-not-working-in-sublime-text-editor?noredirect=1&lq=1) are very much applicable.